# Calling to_json on array returns something different from calling to_json in object

Tags: ruby, json, sinatra

I'm developing an small app using Sinatra. So far so good but I'm having a really small problem and I don't understand why this is happening.

I have a class Note with a custom to_json:

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
   #id
   #name
   #body
   #created_at
   #updated_at

   def to_json(options={})
    {   'id' => self.id,
        'name' => self.name,
        'body' => self.body,
    }.to_json
   end
end
```

If I call:

```
Note.first.to_json
```

It returns:

```
=> "{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"this is the name\",\"body\":\"this is the body\"}"
```

If I add the object inside an array and call to_json of that array

```
array = Array.new
array.push Note.first
array.to_json
```

It returns:

```
=> "[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"this is the name\",\"body\":\"this is the body\",\"updated_at\":\"2014-01-17T22:00:45-03:00\",\"created_at\":\"2013-04-17T21:21:20-03:00\"}]"
```

So the to_json from the class `Note` is not getting called because I still get the `updated_at` and the `created_at`

What am I doing wrong? (btw, I'm using the json gem)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename your `to_json` method to `as_json`, remove `.to_json` on a hash and it should work.

```
def as_json(options={})
  {
   'id' => self.id,
   'name' => self.name,
   'body' => self.body,
  }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize the record before adding it to the array:

```
array = []
array << Note.first.to_json
array.to_json
```

Comment: that still returning what I have in my question :(

Comment: @Andres sorry I had a typo. Try now :)